# Barra de rolagem após usar 100vh

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Setei uma altura para deixa a parte do `header` cobrindo a tela toda. Usei `100vh` na altura e `100vw` largura, porem quando adicionei conteúdo abaixo do `header` apareceu a barra de rolagem do eixo `x` (horizontal).

Eu consertei com `overflow-x : hidden;`, porém sou uma pessoa meio curiosa e gostaria de saber porque apareceu a barra de rolagem.

Meu código é esse:

```js
(function(window){
 'use strict';
 
 var menu = (function(){
       var $btnMenu = document.querySelector('[data-js=menuBtn]');

       function openAndCloseMenu(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $btnMenu.classList.toggle('openMenu');
       }

       function addNewEvent(event, element, callback){
        element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
       }

       return{
        init: function(){
         addNewEvent('click', $btnMenu, openAndCloseMenu);
        }
       }
      }());

 menu.init();
}(window));
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

:root{
    --green: #31FFC0;
    --bgcolor: #242B3E;
    --white: #FFFFFF;
    --svgBgColor: #4F4C61;
    --copostBG: #646178;
    --greeCompost: #72D5B7;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Fira Code', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    background-color: var(--bgcolor);
    color: var(--white);
    position: relative;
}
h1, h2{
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

a,li,ul{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
}

p{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a{
    font-size: inherit;
}

.shadow-white{
    color: var(--white);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255, .4);
}

.shadow-black{
    color: var(--bgcolor);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(36, 43, 62, .4);
}

.shadow-green{
    color: var(--green);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(49, 255, 162, .4);
}

.sub-title{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container_flex{
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0 13px;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 13px;
}

.header_container{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 568px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.header_container::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .5;
    background: url('../img/bg2.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

header .intro-container{
    padding: 0;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
}

.intro-container h1{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: left;
}

.intro-container p{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.45rem;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 5;
}

.btnContat{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--white);
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}

.btnContat::before{
    content: '';
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 15px;
   display: block;
   z-index: 0;
   background-color: var(--white);
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: height .3s ease;
   opacity: .1;
}

.btnContat:hover::before{
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;  
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.link{
    color: var(--white);
    position: relative;
}

.link-branch{
    color: var(--white);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav-menuBtn{
    height: 19px;
    width: 23px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav-menuBtn i{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--white);
}

.nav-menuBtn i:last-child{
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.nav-menuBtn i:nth-child(2){
    align-self: center;
}

.nav-menu{
    background-color:  rgba(36, 43, 62, .9);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

li .link{
    font-size: 2rem;
    overflow: visible;
}
.nav-menu li{
    margin: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
}

li .link::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: var(--green);
    overflow: visible;
    bottom: -12px;
    transition: width .3s ease;
}

li .link:hover::after{
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.openMenu ~ .nav-menu{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 789px){
    .container{
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Antunes</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font/fira_code.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/config.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
    <nav class="nav">
        <button data-js="menuBtn" class="nav-menuBtn"><i></i><i></i><i></i></button>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Projetos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Sobre</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="link-branch" href="index.html" class="nav-logo">Antunes</a>
    </nav>
    <header class="container_flex header_container">

        <section class="container intro-container">
            <h1 class="shadow-green">Gabriel Antunes</h1>
            <p data-js="description" class="sub-title">
                é simpdgfdgesmente uma dfdmulação
                imgfdgfs, efgfgdo
                emgfgfgf pgfffgfdgra
            </p>
            <button class="btnContat" data-js="contatBtn">contato</button>
        </section>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
        <h2 class="shadow-white">
            Laboratório
        </h2>
        <div class="flex-row 2-3col">
            fdsfgdsgfsdfgfgafdgrfdgf
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <articl class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="./js/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tentou usar o atributo `overflow: hidden`? O atributo overflow serve para dizer o que irá acontecer se o conteúdo exceder o tamanho do envoltório.

Comment: [OFF] Falta a letra "e" na *tag* `<articl `.

Comment: "*- [...] porem quando adcionei conteúdo abaixo do header apareceu a barra de rolagem*" Qual o efeito esperado? Pela lógica, o scroll É NECESSÁRIO para o usuário acessar o conteúdo. Se tirar o scroll, tem o mesmo efeito de "você tirar o conteúdo". Se quer esse tal conteúdo dentro do header, deve mencionar na pergunta. Mas, de qualquer forma, se exceder o tamanho da tela, vai aparecer o scroll. A diferença é que o scroll será do header, e não do body. Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar mais informações para seu objetivo?! ;D

Comment: eu usei o overflow-x hidden, porem gostaria de saber o por que deu essa barra de rolagem :/

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- o scroll que eu falo é no eixo x

Comment: Ahhhh sim! É bom informar isso na pergunta, bro! Kk

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- vou por rsrs, eu consertei com overflow-x hidden, porem gostaria de saber o por que acontece.

Comment: Saquei! Quando meu PC resolver ligar, formulo uma resposta.

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- vlw mesmo pela ajuda <3

Answer (score 2):

Você definiu a largura do seu `header` com 100% do *viewport*: `width: 100vw`. Acontece que a barra de rolagem (*scrollbar*) pertence à *viewport*.

[image: Print exemplo]

Logo, deve-se descontar o tamanho dela. **MAAAS**, uma forma melhor é limitar o tamanho dela a 100%: `max-width: 100%;`. Isso resolve a questão dos diferentes tamanhos de *scrollbar* dos navegadores. Limitando o tamanho a `100%` do documento.

Existe uma pergunta sobre isso no SOen: [100vw causing horizontal overflow, but only if more than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one).

Além disso, precisa ajustar a posição do seu `::before`. Você definiu o `position: absolute;`, mas faltou definir a partir de onde ele fica: `top: 0; left: 0;` resolve!

Veja como fica seu código depois de pronto:

```js
(function(window){
 'use strict';
 
 var menu = (function(){
       var $btnMenu = document.querySelector('[data-js=menuBtn]');

       function openAndCloseMenu(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $btnMenu.classList.toggle('openMenu');
       }

       function addNewEvent(event, element, callback){
        element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
       }

       return{
        init: function(){
         addNewEvent('click', $btnMenu, openAndCloseMenu);
        }
       }
      }());

 menu.init();
}(window));
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

:root{
    --green: #31FFC0;
    --bgcolor: #242B3E;
    --white: #FFFFFF;
    --svgBgColor: #4F4C61;
    --copostBG: #646178;
    --greeCompost: #72D5B7;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Fira Code', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400;
    background-color: var(--bgcolor);
    color: var(--white);
    position: relative;
}
h1, h2{
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

a,li,ul{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
}

p{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a{
    font-size: inherit;
}

.shadow-white{
    color: var(--white);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255, .4);
}

.shadow-black{
    color: var(--bgcolor);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(36, 43, 62, .4);
}

.shadow-green{
    color: var(--green);
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(49, 255, 162, .4);
}

.sub-title{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container_flex{
    width: 100vw;
    /* ADICIONEI ISSO: */
    max-width: 100%;
    /* --------------- */
    padding: 0 13px;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 13px;
}

.header_container{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 568px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.header_container::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /* ADICIONEI ISSO: */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* --------------- */
    opacity: .5;
    background: url('../img/bg2.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

header .intro-container{
    padding: 0;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
}

.intro-container h1{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: left;
}

.intro-container p{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.45rem;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 5;
}

.btnContat{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Fira Code';
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--white);
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}

.btnContat::before{
    content: '';
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 15px;
   display: block;
   z-index: 0;
   background-color: var(--white);
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: height .3s ease;
   opacity: .1;
}

.btnContat:hover::before{
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;  
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.link{
    color: var(--white);
    position: relative;
}

.link-branch{
    color: var(--white);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav-menuBtn{
    height: 19px;
    width: 23px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav-menuBtn i{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--white);
}

.nav-menuBtn i:last-child{
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.nav-menuBtn i:nth-child(2){
    align-self: center;
}

.nav-menu{
    background-color:  rgba(36, 43, 62, .9);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

li .link{
    font-size: 2rem;
    overflow: visible;
}
.nav-menu li{
    margin: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
}

li .link::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: var(--green);
    overflow: visible;
    bottom: -12px;
    transition: width .3s ease;
}

li .link:hover::after{
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.openMenu ~ .nav-menu{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 789px){
    .container{
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Antunes</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font/fira_code.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/config.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
    <nav class="nav">
        <button data-js="menuBtn" class="nav-menuBtn"><i></i><i></i><i></i></button>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Projetos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-items">
                <a class="link" href="#" >Sobre</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="link-branch" href="index.html" class="nav-logo">Antunes</a>
    </nav>
    <header class="container_flex header_container">

        <section class="container intro-container">
            <h1 class="shadow-green">Gabriel Antunes</h1>
            <p data-js="description" class="sub-title">
                é simpdgfdgesmente uma dfdmulação
                imgfdgfs, efgfgdo
                emgfgfgf pgfffgfdgra
            </p>
            <button class="btnContat" data-js="contatBtn">contato</button>
        </section>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
        <h2 class="shadow-white">
            Laboratório
        </h2>
        <div class="flex-row 2-3col">
            fdsfgdsgfsdfgfgafdgrfdgf
            <!-- Corrigi as suas tags article que estavam sem o "e" -->
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
            <article class="square_project" data-js="projects"></article>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="./js/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para impedir que o conteúdo da página continue a ser mostrado após a altura do elemento em questão atingir seu valor máximo, isto é, 100%, impeça que a barra de rolagem seja mostrada utilizando a propriedade `overflow: hidden`.

Entretanto, não se deixe enganar: o conteúdo ainda estará lá, você só terá impedido o usuário de poder chegar até ele.

Comment: Nem foi eu que te negative, mas sua solução eh "empurrar a sugeria para debaixo do tapete". Se tem o scroll horizontal eh Pq tem algo errado, e o overflow não eh a resposta para esse erro... Pense nisso

Comment: Deixei isto claro na resposta...